# server thread show connection problems

Tags: java, sockets, server

I created a server thread(using sockets). I recently got a new requirement that I need to add message to the user to notify him when there is a problem with the communication, I added a counter that counts how many exception I have during the communication lose and if it's equal to SERVER_MAX_NUM_TRIES I need to show to the user the message.

I tried many things but it does not work as it is suppose to.

This is my code so far:

```
public ServerNetworkThread()
{
    setName("ServerNetworkThread");
    _port = 5555;
    _excetionCounter = 0;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    _isWorking = true;
    while(_isWorking)
    {
        try
        {
            _serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            _serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            _serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(_port));

            _socket = _serverSocket.accept();
            _socket.setSoTimeout(Consts.CLIENT_SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
            parseCommand();

            _socket.close();
            _serverSocket.close();

            _excetionCounter = 0;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.d("anton","server got exception _excetionCounter="+_excetionCounter);
            e.printStackTrace();
            _excetionCounter++;
            if(_excetionCounter == SERVER_MAX_NUM_TRIES)
            {
                _isWorking = false;
                Logics.getInstance().getNetworkManager().sendCommand(_handler, Consts.Requests.CONNECTION_SERVER_ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void parseCommand() throws IOException
{
    InputStream iStream = _socket.getInputStream();
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(iStream, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
    char[] buf = new char[1024];
    int lettersCount = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
    String request = new String(buf,0,lettersCount);

    String responseStr = parseResponse(request);
    byte[] response = responseStr.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    outToClient.write(response);
    outToClient.flush();
    outToClient.close();
    in.close();

}
```

}

When I simulate a communication problem unplug the Ethernet cable nothing is happening.

UPDATE:

without using the second inner loop I'm getting this exception 
java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

Comment: What is the inner while for? Since has the same condition that the parent one will always enter in this case.
Btw, try changing `IOException` for `Exception` to catch all of them. Or add [SocketException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception(v=vs.110).aspx) too

Comment: That's because you're using the same socket/petition without closing it when you process the petition. So you can close it after parsing the command, or just use a block the thread until client sends new connection

Comment: I'm closing it parseCommand

Comment: My bad I wanted to mean the `_serverSocket`, the error comes because you wanna bind the same address before liberating it as it says. The initialitzation of `_serverSocket` should go out of the while, you just need to bind one time. Or close `_serverSocket` after parsing too.

Comment: You were right, I added  _serverSocket.close(); after closing the socket 
It fixed the exception but now when I'm removeing the cable its still dont get catch segment of the try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120594/discussion-between-raskayu-and-visionix-visionix).